# Python3 extract contents of an .iso file

Tags: python-3.x, extract, iso

I am trying to find a way to extract the contents of an iso image to a designated file path. This can be done using 7-Zip easily, but I can't find a Python way to do it. There seems to be a library `isoparser` https://github.com/barneygale/isoparser, but it does not give many examples of how to do this.

Does anyone have experience doing this or can provide some examples?

Answer (score 2):

I'd switch gears and use [pycdlib](https://github.com/clalancette/pycdlib). Check out this library's example of an [iso extract script](https://github.com/clalancette/pycdlib/blob/master/examples/extract-data.py). Note: I haven't used either pycdlib or isoparser. But the former looks more friendly.

Comment: thanks for that, I just read the documentation on this (https://clalancette.github.io/pycdlib/), and it doesn't seem to be able to extract entire folders from the iso, only single files.

Comment: Just iterate through all the files to extract with list_children() as explained in the "Opening an existing ISO."

Comment: Also check out the author's own tool to extract the iso: https://github.com/clalancette/pycdlib/blob/master/tools/pycdlib-extract-files

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this [lib7zip bindings](https://github.com/topia/pylib7zip).

Example usage:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/topia/pylib7zip
from lib7zip import Archive, formats

archive = Archive("cd.iso", forcetype="Iso")

#extract all items to the directory, directory will be created if it doesn't exist
archive.extract('output_dir')

# iterate over archive contents
for f in archive:
    if f.is_dir:
        continue
    print("; %12s  %s %s" % ( f.size, f.mtime.strftime("%H:%M.%S %Y-%m-%d"), f.path))
```